# Find all instances of a function with a given head and replace their arguments

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to pattern-match all the functions with head `Sin` in list and replace their single input with a value.

```
Clear[a,x,y,z]
testList = {x, Sin[x], Sin[y],x^2*y, g[y,x], h[x,y,z], Cos[Tan[x]]}
testList /. f_Sin[a_] :> (f[a] /. a->10)
```

However, this is giving me

```
{x, Sin[x], Sin[y], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]}
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not just `testList /. Sin[_] -> Sin[10]`?

Comment: @kglr that is also a solution, but I'm new to Mathematica, and would be very much like to learn why my solution doesn't work.

Comment: try also `testList /. _Sin -> Sin[10]`

Comment: consider `testList2 = {x, Sin[x], Sin[y][t], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], 
   Cos[Tan[x]]}; testList2 /. f_Sin[a_] :> (f[a] /. a -> 10)`

Comment: the pattern `_Sin` (and the pattern `f_Sin`) matches _**any expression with Head Sin**_, that is, expressions `Sin[x]` and `Sin[y]` in your `testList`.  But the pattern `_Sin[a_]` is _any expression with Head Sin evaluated at a single argument_ and there are no such expressions in your `testList`.

Comment: Btw, you can do `testList /. (f : Sin)[a_] :> (f[a] /. a -> 10)` to get the desired result.

Comment: @kglr thank you soo much for the responses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kglr recommends is the best practice for what you want to do, but here is pattern that does it your way.

```
testList = {x, Sin[x], Sin[y], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]};
testList /. f : Sin[a_] :> (f /. a -> 10)
```

> ```
> {x, Sin[10], Sin[10], x^2 y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]}
> ```

This works because it recognizes that `f` matches the whole expression `Sin[...]`, so that writing `f[a]` in  `(f[a] /. a -> 10)` is wrong.

This approach is not without it uses. Say you wanted pick out the expressions with the heads `Sin` and `Cos`. Then

```
testList /. f : (Sin | Cos)[a_] :> (f /. a -> 10)
```

> ```
> {x, Sin[10], Sin[10], x^2 y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[10]}
> ```

is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

testList /. Sin[a_] -> (f[a] /. a -> 10)

Hope this helps

Comment: You have no reference to `f` before `->`. Why should it work?

Comment: And why mine doesn't work?

Comment: and note that, this "answer" doesn't work

Comment: May be I have misundestood how the final output should look like? Can you post the list how it should finally look like, please?

Comment: `{{x, Sin[10], Sin[10], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]}}`

Answer (score 0):

You want to choose all items with `Sin` head. And replace them with `Sin[10]`

So you can try

```
{x, Sin[x], Sin[y], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]} /. x_Sin :> Sin[10]
```

notice `x_Sin` , `x` is useless, so we can delete it

```
{x, Sin[x], Sin[y], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]} /. _Sin :> Sin[10]
```

---

Another angle:

Choose all the items look like `Sin[_]` , replace `_` with `10`

```
{x, Sin[x], Sin[y], x^2*y, g[y, x], h[x, y, z], Cos[Tan[x]]} /. Sin[x_] :> Sin[10]
```

the `x` in the `Sin[x_]` can be deleted.